# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, imagemagick, paperclip

I currently have an application using paperclip that allows users to upload their creatives. This has worked flawless thus far when it comes to a user uploading an image file. We have since tested to upload a .mov file and I get this error:

```
Creative Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

The weird thing, this error is only generated on Heroku. I can upload .mov files just fine on my local host.

**My Current Gem Setup:**

```
paperclip (3.4.1, 3.4.0)
paperclip-aws (1.6.7, 1.6.6)
paperclip-ffmpeg (0.10.2)
cocaine (0.5.1, 0.4.2)
```

**Event.rb**

```
has_attached_file :creative, 
                :processors => [:ffmpeg],
                :styles => { 
                  :thumb => [:geometry => "250x150", :format => 'png'], 
                  :custcreative => [:geometry => "275x75", :format => 'png'], 
                  :creativepreview => ["275x195",:png] 
                           },
                :url => "***", 
                :path => "***",
                :s3_domain_url => "***",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml"),
                :bucket => '***',
                :s3_permissions => :public_read,
                :s3_protocol => "http",
                :convert_options => { :all => "-auto-orient" },
                :encode => 'utf8'
```

Spending hours trying to figure out why this works locally but throwing error on Heroku.

I even tried removing the :style setting, but still did not work.

TIA

**EDIT**

```
 Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/MidPen20130413-2-1mzetus.mov[0]'
```

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same problem!!

Comment: Not really. There was some posts written about the same error but all solutions I tried did not work. I have since upgraded to using carrierwave which works good.

Comment: Are you using image cropping (as suggested in Railscasts)? If you are I figured it out.

Comment: Yes. I was using it for thumbnail previews

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is the answer in case any other newbies like us come across the same problem. The issue is with the geometry method that is being used for image cropping. The way it is suggested in railscasts assumes the file is in a local system and that needs to be changed.

**OLD METHOD:**

```
def avatar_geometry(style = :original)
@geometry ||= {}
@geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(avatar.path(style))
end
```

**NEW METHOD**

```
def avatar_geometry(style = :original)
@geometry ||= {}
avatar_path = (avatar.options[:storage] == :s3) ? avatar.url(style) : avatar.path(style)
@geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(avatar_path)
end
```